# Saving Image in python from multiple plot lines

Tags: python, image, plot, save

I am trying to save image to my machine using the below code but I am getting a blank image when I tried opening the image from the saved folder whereas I can see the image in plt.show(), Could someone please help me in saving the image by altering the below code

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
line1, = plt.plot(alpha, train_results, 'b', label="Train AUC")
line2, = plt.plot(alpha, test_results, 'r', label="Test AUC")
plt.legend(handler_map={line1: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=2)})
plt.ylabel('AUC score')
plt.xlabel('n_estimators')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('AUC_.png',dpi=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `plt.savefig()` before `plt.show()`. `plt.show()` clears the figure.